# How to solve Content is not allowed in Prolog error for pdf files?

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfrenderer

I am trying to implement rendering/viewing pdf file by using PdfRenderer API.So I have created a assets folder in res(resources) which has a pdf file named sample.pdf. The following is what my build.gradle file looks like.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.inevitablesol.com.demopdf"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}

//adding aaptOptions
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "pdf"
    }
}
```

And this is my Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.inevitablesol.com.demopdf">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> When I build my project I get the following errors: Error:(1, 1)
>   Error: Content is not allowed in prolog. :app:mergeDebugResources
>   FAILED Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AndroidStudioProjects\DemoPdf\app\src\main\res\assets\sample.pdf:1:1:
> >     Error: Content is not allowed in prolog. Build Failed.

I am new to programming so any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/assets` folder goes under `/main`, not under `/res`. Your build error is basically saying it found something it shouldn't have in your `/res` folder.